# Intersection of a chain of compact sets.

Tags: general-topology

The following is a well known theorem: Let $F_{\alpha} \subset X$ be a sequence of nonempty compact subsets of Hausdorff space $X$ where $\alpha < \nu$ for some ordinal $\nu$. If $F_{\alpha}$ is "decreasing" in the sense that $\alpha_1 < \alpha_2$ then $F_{\alpha_1} \subset F_{\alpha_2}$, then $\bigcap_{\alpha < \nu} F_{\alpha}$ is also compact and nonempty in $X$.

My question: Is this property true in the general case in the following sense? Let $\{K_{\alpha}\}$ be a chain of nonempty compact sets in Hausdorff $X$ then $\bigcap_{\alpha} K_{\alpha}$ is nonempty and compact in $X$. One can see from the finite intersection property that if $X$ were allowed to be compact, then one can conclude the total intersection is nonempty, but what if $X$ is not necessarily compact? In this case one cannot "fix" some compact $K_{\alpha}$ to be the underlying set as in the proof of the descreasing chain case. Does anyone have an idea of a proof or counterexample?

Comment: @BrianMoehring You definitely answered my question, thanks! In that case we can use the FIT in $K_{\beta}$ and conclude the total intersection is nonempty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your chain is nonempty (I believe the empty chain is still a chain, even if it's constantly being removed), then you can pick one of them out arbitrarily, say $K_\beta$.

Then consider the chain $\{K_\alpha \cap K_\beta\}_\alpha$.  The intersection of two compact sets is compact, so it's a chain of compact sets such that $K_\alpha \cap K_\beta \subseteq K_\beta \cap K_\beta$, so all of them are a subset of a fixed set, and also,
$$\bigcap_\alpha K_\alpha = \bigcap_\alpha (K_\alpha \cap K_\beta)$$
so an answer to this reduced problem becomes an answer for yours.